# $T$ can be $\infty$ with positive probability

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, summation, martingales, stopping-times

From Williams' Probability with Martingales

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

How exactly do we know $T$ can be $\infty$ with positive probability

or

$$P(T = \infty) > 0 \text{ ?}$$

I'm guessing that that means there is a positive probability that for some $c$, the sum, $X_1 + \cdots + X_r$, will never exceed $c$ no matter how large $r$ is.

If the partial sums are bounded, then no matter how many terms in the sequence we add, they won't exceed some $c$ so

$$\{r \mid |X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_r| > c\} = \emptyset \text{ ?}$$

Why can't we say that $P(T = \infty) = 1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indicating the dependence of $T$ on $c$ explicitly, you have

$$\{T_c=\infty\}=\{\sup_n|M_n|\le c\}$$

Therefore,

$$\bigcup_{c>0,c\in\Bbb Q}\{T_c=\infty\}=\{\sup_n|M_n|<\infty\}$$

Comment: Thanks John Dawkins ^-^ I think $P(\sup_n |M_n|) < \infty) = 1$? If so then $P(\bigcup_{c>0,c\in\Bbb Q}\{T_c=\infty\}) = 1$ meaning...what? $P(T_c = \infty) > 0 \ \forall \ c \in \ \mathbb R$? I don't think that that necessarily follows

Comment: Meaning $P(T_c=\infty)$ increases to $1$ as $c$ increases to $\infty$.

Comment: John Dawkins, you're using continuity of probability?

Comment: Precisely.$\phantom{bbbbbbbb}$